# How can I avoid razor path error warnings in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My code works fine but I get many warnings such as for the following:

```
@model WebUx.Areas.Administration.ViewModels.Shared.BaseViewModel
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Areas/Administration/Views/Accounts/_Layout.cshtml";
    Session["CurrentUrl"] = Request.Url.ToString();
    Session["CurrentHost"] = Request.Headers["Host"];
}
```

How can I avoid the warning saying Warning

```
    7   
C:\Code J\T69 Dec 8\WebUx\Areas\Administration\Views\Accounts\ShowSummary.cshtml: 
ASP.NET runtime error: Failed to map the path '/'.  
C:\Code J\T69 Dec 8\WebUx\Areas\Administration\Views\Accounts\ShowSummary.cshtml
```

Comment: Do you host your application in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```
Layout = @Url.Content("~/Areas/Administration/Views/Accounts/_Layout.cshtml");
```